# Laravel Forge - Deploying Wordpress + HTTPS is giving "too many redirects"

Tags: wordpress, nginx, laravel-forge

My Nginx config file:

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/www.example.com/before/*;

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example.com;
    root /home/forge/www.example.com;

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/www.example.com/616559/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/www.example.com/616559/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/www.example.com/server/*;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/www.example.com-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DO NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/www.example.com/after/*;
```

Site domain is www.example.com
Aliases: example.com

Any idea?

Comment: try to rename your current .htaccess file and then go to Settings >> Permalink and save permalink. I hope it will helps you.

Comment: When you open developer tools on your browser, under Networking tab. What redirects is the application doing? http to https? https to https? if https forced in your wordpress?

Comment: @dineshkashera Laravel forge uses Nginx, not Apache. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Just posting the solution to anyone in the same situation:

The problem was not with posted Nginx configuration at all, which is correct. 
After a while searching for a solution, I realised that I had two DNS records (in DNS table of my web and domain hosting) pointing to `www.example.com` in DNS table, resulting in that behaviour when accessing the web.

Thanks.